# Numpy masks behaving differently when explicitly written and when referenced?

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to understand numpy masks better and decided to try a simple fizzbuzz exercise (since np arrays are homogenous, 9993 is "fizz", 9995 = "buzz", 9998 = "fizzbuzz"). However, I noticed behavior I cannot understand and was hoping that someone could explain.

In the first case, I created my masks like that:

```
In:
a = np.arange(32)
a[(a % 3 == 0) & (a % 5 == 0)] = 9998
a

Out:
array([9998,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
     11,   12,   13,   14, 9998,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,
     22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29, 9998,   31])

In:
a[a % 3 == 0] = 9993
a[a % 5 == 0] = 9995
a

Out:
array([9998,    1,    2, 9993,    4, 9995, 9993,    7,    8, 9993, 9995,
     11, 9993,   13,   14, 9998,   16,   17, 9993,   19, 9995, 9993,
     22,   23, 9993, 9995,   26, 9993,   28,   29, 9998,   31])
```

Notice that 9998 has not been overwritten by the subsequent steps, as expected (it divides by neither 3 nor 5). So far so good. However, then I tried to be clever and name my masks:

```
In:
a = np.arange(32)
fizz = (a % 3 == 0)
buzz = (a % 5 == 0)
fizzbuzz = fizz & buzz
a[fizzbuzz] = 9998
a

Out:
array([9998,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
     11,   12,   13,   14, 9998,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,
     22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29, 9998,   31])

In:
a[fizz] = 9993
a[buzz] = 9995
a

Out:
array([9995,    1,    2, 9993,    4, 9995, 9993,    7,    8, 9993, 9995,
     11, 9993,   13,   14, 9995,   16,   17, 9993,   19, 9995, 9993,
     22,   23, 9993, 9995,   26, 9993,   28,   29, 9995,   31])
```

From what I could grasp, it would appear that at the "fizzbuzz = fizz & buzz" step, I create a mask such that it provides me with a copy of the array when applied over it. This is in contrast to just writing the mask out, which appears to work as intended and modify the array directly (15 & 30 remain 9998 even after the % 3 and % 5 masks are applied).

My question is why does this happen? From my perspective the logic is absolutely the same in both cases. Writing it as "a[fizz & buzz]" instead of "a[fizzbuzz]" did not help.

Comment: You know how after `x = 2; y = x + 1; x = 4`, `y` is still 3, but `x + 1` is 5? Basically the same thing is happening with `fizz` and `a % 3 == 0`.

Comment: `fizz` and `buzz` both evaluate immediately.  both `fizz[0]` and buzz[0]` are true.  The fact that you later change `a[0]` to another value doesn't change `fizz` or `buzz`.  In your correctly working code, the moral equivalents of `fizz` and `buzz` aren't evaluated until after you've changed `a[0]`.

Comment: Cute solution, by the way!!

Comment: Ah, I see, I didnt realise they evaluate immediately and then maintain those values. Thanks for the help, that explained it!

Comment: `fizz` is a numpy array with boolean dtype.  We call it a mask because of how it is used, not because it has some special evaluation or functional properties.  Creating `fizzbizz` and using it does not change `fizz`

Comment: It might be better to refer to the whole operation as `masking`, rather than focus on `a%3=0` as a `mask`.  The documentation section that talks about `boolean array indexing` does not use the word 'mask'.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that, when you generate the array in first step you got `a = [0,1,2,3,...,31]`. and the comparation that you are doing (first snipet) is with the value in the array and not with de index. so when you do the first replace you got `a=[9998,1,2,9998,4,9998,6...]` then the next replace you are using the values so the compare `9998%3==0` when you are in index 15 is `False` and `9998%5==0` is also `False`

In the seccond case you are using boolean array to acccess `a` then you're acceding with indexs. In this case doesn't mater the value in that index.

if you want the same behavior in both you can modify when you create fizz and buzz

```
a = np.arange(32)
fizzbuzz = (a % 3 == 0) & (a % 5 == 0)
a[fizzbuzz] = 9998

print(a)



fizz = (a % 3 == 0)
buzz = (a % 5 == 0)

a[fizz] = 9993
a[buzz] = 9995

print(a)
```

so the thing is that you are creating fizz and buzz with different arrays y both cases
(sorry for potato english)